# SQL: How to query the average of monthly sum, when some months don't have record?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, average, aggregate-functions

**TL;WR:** How to query the average of monthly sum, when some months don't have record (so should be 0)?

---

### Background

My kids are reporting daily how long they have done chores (in a PostgreSQL database). My dataset then looks like this:

```
date,user,duration

2020-01-01,Alice,120
2020-01-02,Bob,30
2020-01-03,Charlie,10
2020-01-23,Charlie,10

2020-02-03,Charlie,10
2020-02-23,Charlie,10

2020-03-02,Bob,30
2020-03-03,Charlie,10
2020-03-23,Charlie,10
```

I want to know how much, on average, do they do per month. Concretely, the result I want is:

- Alice: 40 `=(120+0+0)÷3`
- Bob: 20 `=(30+0+30)÷3`
- Charlie: 20 `=([10+10]+[10+10]+[10+10])÷3`

### Problem

On some months, I don't have record for some users (e.g., Alice in February and March). Thus, running the following nested query doesn't return the result I want; indeed, this doesn't take in consideration that, because there is no record for these months, Alice's contribution in February and March should be 0 (here the average is wrongly computed as 120).

```sql
-- this does not work
SELECT
    "user",
    round(avg(monthly_duration)) as avg_monthly_sum
FROM (
    SELECT
        date_trunc('month', date),
        "user",
        sum(duration) as monthly_duration
    FROM
        public.chores_record
    GROUP BY
        date_trunc('month', date),
        "user"
) AS monthly_sum
GROUP BY
    "user"
;
-- Doesn't return what I want:
--
-- "unique_user","avg_monthly_sum"
-- "Alice",120
-- "Bob",30
-- "Charlie",20
```

Thus, I have built a quite cumbersome query as follows:

1. List the unique months,
2. List the unique users,
3. Generate the months×users combinations,
4. Add the monthly sum from the original data,
5. Get the average of monthly sum (assuming 'null' = 0).

```sql
SELECT
    unique_user,
    round(avg(COALESCE(monthly_duration, 0))) -- COALESCE transforms 'null' into 0
FROM (
    -- monthly duration with 'null' if no record for that user×month
    SELECT
        month_user_combinations.month,
        month_user_combinations.unique_user,
        monthly_duration.monthly_duration
    FROM
    (
        (
            -- all months×users combinations
            SELECT
                month,
                unique_user
            FROM (
                (
                    -- list of unique months
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        date_trunc('month', date) as month
                    FROM
                        public.chores_record
                ) AS unique_months
                CROSS JOIN
                (
                    -- list of unique users
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        "user" as "unique_user"
                    FROM
                        public.chores_record
                ) AS unique_users
            )
        ) AS month_user_combinations
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            -- monthly duration for existing month×user combination only
            SELECT
                date_trunc('month', date) as month,
                "user",
                sum(duration) as monthly_duration
            FROM
                public.chores_record
            GROUP BY
                date_trunc('month', date),
                "user"
        ) AS monthly_duration
        ON (
            month_user_combinations.month = monthly_duration.month
            AND
            month_user_combinations.unique_user = monthly_duration.user
        )
    )
) AS monthly_duration_for_all_combinations
GROUP BY
    unique_user
;
```

This query works, but is quite bulky.

### Question

**How to query the average of monthly sum more elegantly than above, taking “no record ⇒ monthly sum = 0” into account?**

Note: it is safe to assume that I want to compute the average on the months that have *at least one record* only (i.e. it's normal not to consider December or April here.)

---

### MWE

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.chores_record
(
    date date NOT NULL,
    "user" text NOT NULL,
    duration integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (date, "user")
);

INSERT INTO
    public.chores_record(date, "user", duration)
VALUES
    ('2020-01-01','Alice',120),
    ('2020-01-02','Bob',30),
    ('2020-01-03','Charlie',10),
    ('2020-01-23','Charlie',10),
    ('2020-02-03','Charlie',10),
    ('2020-02-23','Charlie',10),
    ('2020-03-02','Bob',30),
    ('2020-03-03','Charlie',10),
    ('2020-03-23','Charlie',10)
;
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (e.g. missing data) in application code

Comment: @Strawberry sounds interesting, but I'm not sure to fully understand. Could you please detail or provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CTE to construct a calendar-table:

---

```
-- EXPLAIN
WITH cal AS ( -- The unique months
        SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('mon', zdate) AS tick
        FROM chores_record
        )
, cnt AS (      -- the number of months (a scalar)
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS nmonth
        FROM cal
        )
SELECT
        x.zuser
        , SUM(x.duration) AS tot_duration
        , SUM(x.duration) / SUM(c.nmonth) AS Averarage_month -- this is ugly ...
FROM cal t
JOIN cnt c ON true -- This is ugly
LEFT JOIN chores_record x ON date_trunc('mon', x.zdate) = t.tick
GROUP BY x.zuser
        ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need two additional datasets for this: the list of kids and the list of months:

```
with
    k as (/* list of kids */
        select distinct "user" from chores_record),
    m as (/* list of months in format "yyyy-mm-01" */
        select distinct date_trunc('month', "date") as "month" from chores_record),
    d as (/* sums by moths and kids */
        select
            date_trunc('month', "date") as "month",
            "user",
            sum(duration) as duration
        from chores_record
        group by 1, 2)
select
    m."month",
    k."user",
    coalesce(d.duration, 0) as duration
from
    k cross join m left join d on (k."user" = d."user" and m."month" = d."month")
order by "month", "user";

┌────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│         month          │  user   │ duration │
├────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00+02 │ Alice   │      120 │
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00+02 │ Bob     │       30 │
│ 2020-01-01 00:00:00+02 │ Charlie │       20 │
│ 2020-02-01 00:00:00+02 │ Alice   │        0 │
│ 2020-02-01 00:00:00+02 │ Bob     │        0 │
│ 2020-02-01 00:00:00+02 │ Charlie │       20 │
│ 2020-03-01 00:00:00+02 │ Alice   │        0 │
│ 2020-03-01 00:00:00+02 │ Bob     │       30 │
│ 2020-03-01 00:00:00+02 │ Charlie │       20 │
└────────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

And the last step is the calculation of the averages:

```
with
    ...
select
    k."user",
    avg(coalesce(d.duration, 0)) as duration
from
    k cross join m left join d on (k."user" = d."user" and m."month" = d."month")
group by k."user"
order by k."user";

┌─────────┬─────────────────────┐
│  user   │      duration       │
├─────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Alice   │ 40.0000000000000000 │
│ Bob     │ 20.0000000000000000 │
│ Charlie │ 20.0000000000000000 │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would recommend `generate_series()` to construct the calendar table, then aggregation. The upside is that it works even if there are months where no user was active.

```
select u."user", avg(coalesce(c.duration, 0)) avg_duration 
from (
    select generate_series(date_trunc('month', min(date)), date_trunc('month', max(date)), '1 month') as dt
    from chores_record
) d
cross join (select distinct "user" from chores_record) u
left join (
    select "user", date_trunc('month', date) as dt, sum(duration) as duration
    from chores_record c 
    group by "user", date_trunc('month', date)
) c on c."user" = u."user" and c.dt = d.dt
group by u."user"
```

`generate_series()` generates all starts of months between the earliest and latest date in the table. Then we `cross join` that with the list of distinct users (in a real life situation, you would probably have a referential table to store the users, that you would use instead). Then, we aggregate the original table by user and month, and `left join` it with the user/month combinations. The final step is outer aggregation.

Comment: `generate_series()` is both smart and powerful, thanks: that's exactly the kind of “smarter ways” I was looking for! (Small typo: the penultimate line should read `[…] and c.dt = d.dt`)

Comment: @ebosi: indeed. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

As the use case was smaller (not millions of rows), a simple approach is to separately find

1. the total hours per user and
2. total distinct months across all users

join the 2 to get the answer

```
select "user", totalHours/monthCount from
(select "user", sum(duration) totalHours from chores_record group by "user") as a,
(select count(distinct(to_char(date, 'YYYYMM'))) monthCount from chores_record) as b
;
```

```
Alice,40
Bob,20
Charlie,20
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.